# Error compiling Java using Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

java.io.FileSystem is not public in java.io; cannot be accessed from outside package
This is the line the complier points to

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
```

I don't understand why it cannot be accessed. Here are the imports

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.*;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `java.io.FileSystem` AFAIK. The closest is `java.nio.FileSystem`

Comment: @nhahtdh and it is also not what is needed

Comment: i would recommend not doing `*` (star) imports.

Comment: you also imported the wrong `Paths` object.

Answer (score 4):

wrong `FileSystem` object as well as the wrong `Paths` object.  You want:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```

You are dealing with the Hadoop FileSystem not the default Java implementation.  Recall that you do `hadoop fs -ls` where `fs` means file system on the command line.

Comment: Yes, hadoop `FileSystem` is another possibility. I just make a guess to `nio`, since there is also the `import java.nio.file.Paths;`. But looking at the import alone is not enough to know which class is actually needed. (But making a guess for hadoop is quite relevant in this case)

Comment: @nhahtdh oh i didnt even see that, OP also imported the wrong Paths object

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
import java.io.FileSystem;
```

with

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
```